# Why can't I save greek text in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

This happens when I try to write Greek in Eclipse as a string.

[image: Error dialog box]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Preferences > General > Workspace > Text file encoding > UTF-8 (or whatever you want that supports your character encoding set).

You might also have to fix it in the project preferences if this has been set there.